# jQuery refresh stops jQuery hover from working

Tags: php, jquery, html, refresh

I'm using the script below to refresh a div when the text 'view more' is clicked. The div loads a bunch of random images from the rotate.php file. For some reason though, the jquery hover effects that I have applied no longer work after the div has been refreshed. I did try adding the jquery hover script to the rotate.php file, but that stops the refresh script from working... :S Does anyone have any ideas on how you could fix this? :)

```
<div class="headingtext">
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function() {
  $("#refresh").click(function(evt) {
     $(".feature").load("rotate.php")
     evt.preventDefault();
  })
})
</script><a id="refresh" href="#">View More</a>
        </div>

        <div class="feature">
            <?php include('rotate.php') ?>
        </div>
```

The jquery I have applied to the images, but stops working after refresh:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $(".feature img").hover(function() {
  $(this).stop().animate({opacity: "0.5"}, 'slow');
},
function() {
  $(this).stop().animate({opacity: "1"}, 'slow');
});
});
```

The PHP (rotate.php):

```
<?php 
$random = "random.txt";
$fp = file($random);
shuffle($fp);
$keys = array_rand($fp, 3);
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++):
$rl = $fp[$keys[$i]]; 
echo $rl;
endfor;
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use the `on` function ( http://api.jquery.com/on/ )

replace :

```
 $(".feature img").hover(function() {
```

by

```
$(".feature img").on("mouseover", function() {
```

Comment: Thank you~! :D the on function actually wasn't working for me, so I'll just use live for the time being :)

Comment: Function "on" was added in 1.7 version ;)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what TeChn4K said

1. You should use both mouseenter and mouseleave (or mouseover and mouseout respectively) to handle both events
2. Starting with jQuery 1.7 you should switch to using .on() instead of .live() ... live will be deprecated in near future

Comment: Seriously ?! Live will be deprecated ? I didn't know "on" function

Comment: Be careful with how to use .on() It has to be bound to an "element that currently exists and that will be higher in the document tree". I.E. you'll need to bind the handler with .on() to an element that will be traversed when the event is bubbling. Usually you take "document" because it will always be reached by bubbling events. $(document).on("mouseover", "SELECTOR HERE", function(e) {...});